# aws cloud filter metric for glue logs /aws-glue/python-jobs/

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am unable to create metric via Terraform
it's not recognizing the log path as log name.

```
data "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "aws_glue_log" {
   
    name = "/aws-glue/python-jobs/"

}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "event_filter" {
  name           = "someNAme"
  pattern        = "ALERT"
  log_group_name = data.aws_cloudwatch_log_group.aws_glue_log.name
  metric_transformation {
    name      = "filtermetric"
    namespace     = "Glue"
    value         = "1"
    default_value = "0"
  }
}

Error: No log group named /aws-glue/python-jobs/ found
11:21:34  
11:21:34
```

i can create metric via console

Comment: The error is pretty clear. There is no log group with that name. Did you intend to use a resource to create a log group instead of using the data source?

Comment: @MarkoE  /aws-glue/python-jobs/ is standard log group for glue jobs its always there

Comment: If it is there, why is there an error about the log group that is missing?